Why is extra space being added to bottom of the "mat-form-field" tag
I tried to create a table and one column has a input field i used mat-form-field to create that input field.The following is the how i did it:
<ng-container matColumnDef="marks" >
    <th mat-header-cell class="mat-header-cell" *matHeaderCellDef style="text-align: center;">Marks</th>
        <td mat-cell class="mat-cell" data-header="Marks" *matCellDef="let student" style="text-align: center;" >
            <mat-form-field  class="formfield" appearance="outline" ><mat-label>Marks</mat-label>
            <input class="input" matInput type="number"></mat-form-field>
        </td>
</ng-container>

When I inspected with dev-tools in the following class is added to a div class="mat-mdc-form-field-subscript-wrapper mat-mdc-form-field-bottom-align" which creates the space.

By default, Angular Material reserves one extra line at the bottom of each form field for error messages and hints, see the docs. You can use subscriptSizing="dynamic" on the form field to dynamically allocate the space as needed, so no space is taken if there are no errors or hints. Note that this may cause layout shifts. You can also set it for all form field appearances in  your component, module or app with the MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS injection token.
